# How does autofac determine lifetime scope on injected parameters

Tags: c#, autofac

I have been having a nasty Memory Leak issue while using Autofac, which I think I may have resolved.  But, I am curious about if the service `StatsService` injected in the `StatsRefreshMessageHandler` class is using the lifetime scope of the `Helpers` class which called it.

Register Service

```
builder.RegisterType<StatsService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

My helpers class is injected with a lifetime scope, it then calls the appropriate message handler.  In this example it will be the `StatsRefreshMessageHandler`

```
public class Helpers
  {     

    private ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;
        private ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;  

        public Helpers(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
        {
            _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;  
        }

        public void ProcessMessage<T>(T message) where T : class
        {
            //Voodoo to construct the right message handler type
            Type handlerType = typeof(IMessageHandler<>);
            Type[] typeArgs = { message.GetType() };
            Type constructed = handlerType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
                //Handle the message
            using (var messageScope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var handler = messageScope.Resolve(constructed);
                var methodInfo = constructed.GetMethod("Handle");
                  //this is where it call the message handler
                methodInfo.Invoke(handler, new[] { message }); 
            }

         }
   }
```

And the class (`StatsRefreshMessageHandler`) below uses standard IOC Injection... But, the question here is where is StatsService resolving from?  I assume it is from the lifetime scope of the caller (`Helpers`), but if it is resolving from the root Kernel, then I still am going to have problems.

```
public class StatsRefreshMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<StatsRefreshMessage>
{
    private readonly StatsService _statsService;

    public StatsRefreshMessageHandler(StatsService statsService)
    {
        _statsService = statsService;
    }

    public void Handle(StatsRefreshMessage message)
    {
       _statsService.UpdateStatsCache(DateTime.UtcNow);
       Console.WriteLine("DONE STATS");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is some detailed documentation about how lifetime scope is determined for objects on the Autofac site.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/index.html) That can probably help clear up some of the questions you may have.

Some quick answers:

- The `handler` you resolve from the `messageScope` will go in the lifetime scope for which it was registered:

  - `SingleInstance` registration will come from the container so it can be shared later with other resolve calls.
  - `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and `InstancePerDependency` will come from the `messageScope` and will be disposed when `messageScope is disposed.
- The `StatsService` in the constructor of `StatsRefreshMessageHandler` will also come from `messageScope` because that's where the handler (the consumer) is being resolved. It will also obey the lifetime scope registration as noted above (e.g., if `StatsService` is `SingleInstance` it will end up in the container).